# How to count the number of times a token comes up in a string in Javacc?

Tags: javacc

How can I count the number of times a token is contained in a string when parsing with Javacc? Do I need to keep a integer then increment this each time the token is shown? how?

Answer (score 1):

Use a token manager decl to declare a counter. Increment it in a token action.  See the docs and the FAQ for more: http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.16 .